# From HashMap how to ignore duplicate key and value using java 8 streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have list of task elements,  From that I need to create hashMap
Here my concenr is like, If I put duplicate key , which is existing in  hashmap , in that case it should ignore, continue  to add remaining objects.

```
private static Map<String, Task> currentRunningTask = new HashMap<String, Task>();
```

currentRunningTask having following elements like

```
(t1,task1)
(t2,task2)
```

if suppose I try  to  add duplicate key like

```
(t2,task2)
```

ignore both key and value. result should be

```
(t1,task1)
    (t2,task2)
```

This is code code i wrote

```
currentRunningTask = tasksList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(Task::getTaskID, task -> task));
```

Comment: Use `Collectors.toConcurrentMap(Task::getTaskID, task -> task, (a,b)->a)`

Comment: Provided solution working, Once more  concern like ,In the list  of  tasks.

Comment: Provided solution working, Once more  concern like ,In the list  of  tasks, if duplicate task2 is instance of Xobject type then , append that to  same same key corresponding value

Comment: The third argument, i.e. `(a,b)->a` tells what to do with two values mapping to the same key. `a` and `b` are the two values. Mapping to just `a` implies keeping the old value. You can change it to whatever logic you want.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Provide a `BinaryOperator` as a third argument of `toConcurrentMap` collector method. The operator should decide how to deal with duplicates. The simplest (and most common) solution is to ignore them:

```
toConcurrentMap(Task::getTaskID, task -> task, (u, v) -> u)
// or
toConcurrentMap(Task::getTaskID, identity(), (u, v) -> u)
```

---

When you're collecting into a `Map` (either using `toMap` or `toConcurrentMap`), you may provide 2 to 4 arguments into that method:

1. `Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper` *(required)*

   Function mapping the input object into a key.
2. `Function<? super T, ? extends V> BinaryOperator<U> valueMapper` *(required)*

   Function mapping the input object into a value.
3. `BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction` *(optional)*

   Binary operator dealing with values having same keys. It receives as input two values and you have to decide which one should remain in the map.

   The decision logic may be sophisticated, though the most used approach is to pick the first value:

   ```
   (u, v) -> u
   ```

   By default the `toMap` method uses `throwingMerger` :

   ```
   (u,v) -> { throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Duplicate key %s", u)); }
   ```
4. `Supplier<M> mapSupplier` *(optional)*

   Supplier providing an instance of `Map`. Using a lambda you can provide an existing map like following, but this is not encouraged, as it adds a side-effect to functional collector:

   ```
   () -> yourExistingMap
   ```

   By default `toMap` and `toConcurrentMap` use `HashMap::new` and `ConcurrentHashMap::new` respectively.